# p4 integ command when file is added and deleted in source component

Tags: perforce

Need to know how p4 integ command works in below situation

I have added one new file in source component and edited some text  and deleted the same file .

for that i have three CLs CL1, CL2 ,CL3...

Now i want to perform p4 merge to merge the changes in destination component

Can anybody tell me how can i perform the above operation using p4 integ because add and edit fine but when trying to perform delete operation it will failed as this file is not exists in destination comopnent

Comment: Yes, you can integrate the deletion of a file to another branch. What version of the server are you using? What precise command did you issue? What exact error message did you receive? What aspect of it seems to you as though it has failed?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to integrate the three changelists individually but submit them as a single target changelist, i.e.:

```
p4 integ source@1 target
p4 integ source@2 target
p4 resolve -as
p4 integ source@3 target
p4 submit
```

The first command will open the target for "branch".  The second command will leave the target open for "branch" and schedule a resolve that will pull the source@2 edits into it (it will wind up being a modified or "dirty" branch).  The third command will throw an error because the target can't be open for branch and open for delete in the same changelist.

There are two alternate ways to do this:

A) Integrate all the changes as a unit instead of specifying each change manually:

```
p4 integ source target
```

The end result of this will be "all revisions already integrated", because "p4 integrate" will look at the sum total of all the changes together, apply them to the target, and come up with a net effect of nil -- the file in the source has been deleted, the target file doesn't exist, so it's a wash.

B) Create one change in the target for each change in the source:

```
p4 integ source@1 target
p4 submit
p4 integ source@2 target
p4 resolve -as
p4 submit
p4 integ source@3 target
p4 submit
```

This will bring each change over cleanly -- the first changelist will be a clean branch of the source revision, the second changelist will be a clean copy, and the third changelist will be a delete.